# Windows Media Player Time Position

Tags: vba, ms-access

I embedded the Windows Media Player in a Microsoft Access form. I need to start playing videos from a specific time position. How can I set up the start position in VBA?
This is the code where I need to control WindowsMediaPlayer object, when clicking on a form list item the record should start playing let say... from 5th minute:

```html
Sub SearchList_Click()
    Me.WindowsMediaPlayer.URL = Me.SearchList.Column(2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
Me.WindowsMediaPlayer.Contents.CurrentPosition=300
```

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/object-model-reference-for-scripting
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/controls-object
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/controls-currentposition